# App downloaded from appstore crash in 9.3 lower version Devices

Tags: ios, app-store, crash-reports, twitter-fabric

As I released my app in AppStore, some users made feedback said that our app crashed when open it, and this situation happened only on iOS 9.2.x devices.

I have debugged the app in my test device. But in Debug mode the crash not happened anymore and I download app from App Store the crash happens again. Even more strange is that Fabric can't catch any crash report.

What can I do to find the reason of the crash and resolve this issue. Is there anybody have similar conditions?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AnalyzingCrashReports/AnalyzingCrashReports.html

Comment: @Sneak I don't know why the crash list in `Xcode -> Organizer->Crashes` sometimes can't be correctly showed or updated and other time the crash list is OK.

Comment: **Did you read the documentation?** If you did, you would notice: Also, allow up to three days between when you first distribute your
app and when crash reports appear in Xcode. To maintain a good user
experience, crash data is sent from user devices to Apple **when the
user allows.**

Comment: Actually I have't carefully read the documents, but I had fetched some crash logs by the way the document mentioned. Come back for my question, I want to find the reason of why my Application download from Appstore crash on ios 9.3 lower device, and other devices OK.

Comment: @Sneak By the way, I didn't find some useful information by the crash logs even if they were symbolicated.

Comment: It is impossible to find out why the crash occus for us without any logs etc. Have you tried it in a simulator with that version of iOS ?

Comment: Running on simulator or device by Xcode every thing is OK, crash only happens on Appstore version and TestFlight Version.

Comment: If crash happens in testflight you can "simply" test it if the crash occurs when you open your app you know what code gets called, and by disabling lines of code you can look what produces the crash. It is however impossible to give you any answer on what it can be other than the documentation I linked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved！

I haven't notice that I have compile and upload this version by the newest version of Xcode -- Xcode 8.2.1, After I change to the old IDE, I found every things turns OK. And I found some useful documents [there](https://openradar.appspot.com/28371396) and some developers had also counted the similar question, this is their [discussion](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/60919).

So the final way to resolve this question is ***DELETE*** the `P3` color space and 16 bit images.

Steps:

1. Create an Inspectable .ipa file.  In the Xcode Organizer (Xcode->Window->Organizer), select an archive to inspect, click “Export...", and choose "Export for Enterprise or Ad-Hoc Deployment". This will create a local copy of the .ipa file for your app.
2. Locate that .ipa file and change its the extension to .zip.
3. Expand the .zip file. This will produce a Payload folder containing your .app bundle.
4. Open a terminal and change the working directory to the top level of your .app bundle
   cd path/to/Payload/your.app
5. Use the find tool to locate Assets.car files in your .app bundle as shown below:
   find . -name 'Assets.car'
6. Use the assetutil tool to find any 16-bit or P3 assets, in each Assets.car your application has as shown below. :
   sudo xcrun --sdk iphoneos assetutil --info /path/to/a/Assets.car > /tmp/Assets.json
7. Examine the resulting /tmp/Assets.json and look for any contents containing “DisplayGamut": “P3” and its associated “Name".  This will be the name of your imageset containing one or more 16-bit or P3 assets.
8. Replace those assets with 8-bit / sRGB assets, then rebuild your app.